# ¿Por qué no se elimina una fila del DOM, al utilizar React.js y Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

Estoy tratando de eliminar una fila de una tabla. El objeto que está en dicha fila se elimina correctamente de la base de datos, pero no consigo que se elimine del DOM en el mismo instante, sino que tengo que recargar la página para que desaparezca.

Estoy utilizando *redux* para el manejo del estado.

¿Cómo podría hacer que se borre en el instante?

**Aquí renderizo la tabla y hago el dispatch para eliminar la fila**

```
// Eliminar productos

    // Eliminar productos
    const handleEliminar = (e) => {
    
        dispatch( productoSeleccionado(e) );
        dispatch( eventStartDelete() );
    
    }
```

Y llamo a la función `handleEliminar` en un botón dentro de la tabla

```
    <table className="table table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style={{ width: 100 }}>ID</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Nombre</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Precio</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Stock</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {body && body.map( b =>
                <tr key={b.id}>
                    <td>{b.id}</td>
                    <td>{b.nombre}</td>
                    <td>{b.precio}</td>
                    <td>{b.stock}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button 
                            className="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                            onClick={() => handleActua(b) }
                        >
                            Editar
                        </button>
                        &nbsp;
                        <button 
                            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                            onClick={ () => handleEliminar(b) } 
                        >
                            Eliminar
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Así se lanza la acción**

```
    // Elimina de la BD
    export const eventStartDelete = () =>{
    
        return async( dispatch, getState ) => {
    
            const { id } = getState().coffe.active;
    
            try {
    
                const resp = await fetchConToken(`productos/${ id }`, {}, 'DELETE');
                const body = await resp.json();
    
                if( body.id ) {
                    dispatch( eventDeleted() )
                } else {
                    Swal.fire('Error', body.msg, 'error');
                }
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
    
        }
    }
    
    // Elimina el evento
    const eventDeleted = () => ({ type: types.eventDeleted });
```

**Y por último el reducer**

```
    // Elimina los eventos
    case types.eventDeleted:
        
        return {
            ...state,
            body: state.body.filter(
                b => ( b.id !== action.id ) 

            ),
            active: null
        }
```

**Aquí ya he presionado el botón de eliminar**

Como pueden ver, se ejecuta la acción de eliminar, en este caso el producto *leche*, pero este aún se encuentra en el `store` y no desaparece hasta que recargue la página.

[image: Eliminar]

Comment: Esta seguro que `const { id } = getState().coffe.active` si le trae el id seleccionado? Porque si ese active lo setea la funcion `productoSeleccionado` ahi puede estar el problema

Comment: Si, el active lo setea la funcion productoSeleccionado. Esta mal que lo haga asi? En las acciones funciona asi: 

// Posiciona el producto en el campo active
export const productoSeleccionado = ( usuario ) => ({

    type: types.uiEventSetActive,
    payload: usuario

});

Y en el reducer 

        case types.uiEventSetActive:

            return {
                ...state,
                active: action.payload
            }

Como deberia de hacerlo?

Comment: Porque hasta donde tengo entendido, los dispatch no se ejecutan de manera sincrona, por lo tanto, cuando llamas al segundo dispatch no puedes estar seguro que el primero ya se ejecuto completamente, entonces es probable que por esa razón, el segundo dispatch te siga tomando los valores "anteriores"

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, tiene mucho sentido ya que aveces si se ejecutaba como quería y otras veces no, agregué un setTimeOut con un tiempo de medio segundo al dispatch de cargar eventos en el useEffect, no creo que sea la mejor solución pero de momento me sirve. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un estado que se actualice cuando ejecutas la función para eliminar.

Primero lo creas:

```
const [updateTrigger, setUpdateTrigger] = useState({});
```

Luego creas un `useEffect()` (si es que no tienes uno creado ya) y entre los corchetes pones el estado:

```
useEffect(() => {
    
},[updateTrigger]);
```

Por último en `handleEliminar()` actualizas el estado con un valor random, por ejemplo así:

```
const handleEliminar = (e) => {

  dispatch( productoSeleccionado(e) );
  dispatch( eventStartDelete() );
  // Activar trigger
  setUpdateTrigger(Math.random())

}
```

De esa forma, el `useEffect()` al detectar cambios re-renderizará el componente y actualizará los cambios en el DOM al instante sin la necesidad de recargar la página.

Comment: Me fue muy util la respuesta! Lo unico que agregue fue un await al dispatch para eliminar el evento, ya que se disparaba de nuevo la accion de cargar los productos y luego se eliminaba, asi que ahora se elimina y luego con tu ayuda se cargan los productos. Gracias bro segunda vez que me salvas.